# Not able to add GooglePlayServices (GCM) in Android Studio (Version 1.3.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, dex

I'm trying to add google play services for GCM in my app but couldn't achieve it.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

If I remove **compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'** then there is no problem in building. Where I'm going wrong?

Build.gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.yyy.zzz"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}

dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
    incremental true
    preDexLibraries false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android:multidex:0.1'
compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.4.2'
 }
```

Comment: plz share your build.gradle file content

Comment: The way how GCM should be integrated has been changed recently. 
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: You do not have added "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" in your build.gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be having outdated **support repositories** in **sdk mananger**

Try This:

Right Click on **app** and **Open module settings** on **Dependencies** Tab

click **'+'** icon and add there **com.google.android.gms:play-services** and click search icon and add that dependency the right version should popup according to your repositories.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: 8.1.0 is what the latest

Comment: then add it from there it should automatically resolve from the internet and you are ready to go.

Comment: Yup. Its working now. Thanks a lot bro.

How can I add just GCM instead of whole play services library.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the dependencies, try to remove the `build/` and `app/build/` folders, then build the project again.

If it does not fix your issue, you will need to provide the full gradle log.

Comment: I have removed both the folders but it is giving same error still